# Objects are not valid components after successful page render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, next.js

I'm fetching data for a page load using [Next.js](https://zeit.co/docs/examples/next). I'm loading a markdown file and parsing it into an array of child components that should be compatible react dom nodes using [Marksy](https://github.com/cerebral/marksy). Everything seems to work correctly for a brief moment where I see the correct content on the page by rendering my `compiled(markdown).tree` using the rough following structure:

```
static async getInitialProps ({query}) {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/api/test')
  const json = await res.json()
  return { content: compile(json.data).tree }
}

render () {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.content}
    </div>
  )
}
```

My array of data has the following shape:

```
[{"type":"h1","key":"0","ref":null,"props":{"children":["Welcome to the Jungle"]},"_owner":null,"_store":{}}]
```

Within a half second, React-Redbox throws an error though that says this:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `_class`.
```

I'm using react 15.4.2

Why am I getting an error show up after a successful render to the page? Thanks!

Comment: What does `http://localhost:4000/api/test` return? Markdown file?

Comment: A markdown string.

Comment: or json object with markdown string? Because you have used `.json()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All React elements require an additional `$$typeof:
>   Symbol.for('react.element')` field declared on the object for security
>   reasons.

Adding this property should fix the problem

Source: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I was able to get it to work with createElement but IU'm still confused why the initial successful render?

Answer (score 0):

We can not render `object/array` directly inside `jsx`, error is explaining everything, you are trying to render `content` that contains following keys:

`{type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}`

Instead of rendering `object/array` render specific value like rendering `type` value of that `object`:

```
render () {
   return (
     <div>
       {this.props.content[0].type}
     </div>
   )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the weird thing is that it s working first and THEN the error comes. Why would that be if it's "not possible" ?

Comment: because initially `content` is not having any value you are doing a async call to fetch the data once you get the data then only `content` has that array, and then it tries to render that and throwing the error. To verify that simply assign the string to `content` instead of that data it will not throw any error :)

Comment: return this once you get the data and check it will not throw the error: `return { content: "Hello" }`

Comment: Thanks, I do actually get that part of it but it's actually rendering the server response CORRECTLY initially and THEN the error comes in.